# What is the best way to check for unique (SQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple MVC application in Java with db (Postgres) and table named users with the following columns:

```
name,email,age,birthday
```

One of the function: to register, the user should provide name and email. Both Fields must be unique in table (unique name and unique email)

To validate user input i use the following sql

```
select * from users where email = ? or name = ?
```

If the query return one column then user's data is not unique.

With help of `JavaMelody` I have noticed that this query is the longest one among others (11 ms)  How can i speed up this?

BTW

From official docs, Postgres doesn't recommend to create index with multiple columns.

EDIT()
in answers I have seen that i should to add unique constraint add catch exception if this exist, but using my query i can check which parameter is not unique

Example:

```
public Optional<String> isUnuque(final Users user) {
        final Users dbUser = this.repository.findByEmailOrName(user.getEmail(), user.getName(),user.getSteamId());
        if (dbUser != null) {
            if (user.getEmail().equals(dbUser.getEmail())) {
                return Optional.of("Email is not unique");
            }else if(user.getName().equals(dbUser.getName())) {
                return Optional.of("Name is not unique");
            }
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
```

Comment: email is unique so it will save in running the query if you check email first (remove OR condition). then check if name (login id) later on.

Comment: So index the columns separately, the query planner will figure out how to use them.

Comment: Where in the docs did you find the recommendation that you shouldn't create an index with multiple columns? Just create a unique index (or constraint) on `(name, email)`. There is no way you can reliably check uniqueness from your Java code

Comment: `From official docs, Postgres doesn't recommend to create index with multiple columns.` Huh? There is nothing wrong with composite indexes. Or composite candidate keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put unique constraint on the fields name and email in the database. Then when you try to insert, if it's not unique, it will return an error.

Answer (score 0):

Using a query to check if a particular record exists would not the an optimized solution as the number of records would increase in future.Instead of that add a unique contraint for those 2 fields and then catch the exception in your code.

If you are using spring you could catch the org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException

```
try {
    some_repository.save(new User(..));
}
catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
    System.out.println("User already exists!");
}
```

If you are not using spring catch SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

```
try {
    ps.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO User....");
} catch (SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e) {
    // Duplicate user
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // Other SQL Exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check unique values in column using below query:

for single column:

```
select (case when count(distinct column1 ) = count(column1)
             then 'Unique'
             else 'Duplicates'
        end)
from table_name;
```

for mutiple column:

```
select (case when count(distinct column1 ) = count(column1) and count(distinct column2 ) = count(column2)
             then 'Unique'
             else 'Duplicates'
        end)
from table_name;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try one or a combination of the following:

1. select 1 from users where email = ? or name = ? // returning "*" is not optimal and should be avoided; only return columns that you will use.
2. select count(*) from users where email = ? or name = ?  // like #1, but returns a count.
3. select count(*) from users where email+name = the_email+the_name  // introduces an concatenation operation in place of an OR but reduces condition to a single expression.
4. If you don't mind an extra column, save the concatenated email+name in its own column, and query that column to test for uniqueness.

Adding a unique constraint only works if you want to delay uniqueness checking until you're ready to save.   If you want to check for uniqueness earlier than that you'll have to issue a query.

Comment: And suppose someone adds a duplicate after the query executes but before the insert? You cannot do just the query: you need the constraint.